# How to disable array of days of week using Angular Material Datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

That's how it was written in documentation of angular material datepicker:

```
this.expressSenderDate = (d: Date | null): boolean => {
      const day = (d || new Date()).getDay();
      console.log(day);
      // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
      return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
    };
```

If you try this, in console you'll see the current day of week number (from 0 to 6).
BUT: I'll get this values (from 0 to 6) by http request as an array. I want to disable days of week using this array. But it did't work. I saw a solution to disable determined dates but it's not what I want and that solution didn't work for me.

Comment: if you store in a variable the array, e.g. `this.forbiddenWeekDays=[0,3,2]` you can use `return day.indexOf(this.forbiddenWeekDays)<0` -you should return false when you want to "disable" the day-

Comment: I tried this:
`
const forbidden = [0, 3, 6];

    this.expressSenderDate = (d: Date | null): boolean => {
      const day: any = (d || new Date()).getDay();
      console.log(day);
      // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
      return day.indexOf(forbidden) < 0;
    };
`
It's not working

Comment: ::glups:: sorry, is `forbidden.indexOf(day)`: see stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s836tn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-filter-example.ts